# How to add Foundation framework to Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6, laravel-5.5

How can I add lattest Zurb Foundation framework to Laravel 5.5? I want to change default Bootstrap framework to Foundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I add the lattest Zurb Foundation framework to Laravel 5.5.

Hope it will help somebody.

1. Open package.json and remove bootstrap entry and then install lattest foundation-site version using npm:
   `npm install foundation-sites@latest --save-dev`
2. Then go to **resources/assets/sass/app.scss**
   You can import settings here if you have your own, if not you just need to import   foundation.scss with default foundation settings:

`@import "~foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss";
@include foundation-everything(true);`

3. Next step you need to go to **node_modules/foundation-sites/sass/foundation.scss** and do that steps:

   - Uncomment there a default **settings** import block which can be found at row number 18 or 20.
   - Then swap that **settings** import block with **util** import block placed right below the first one, because **settings.scss** needs **util** therefore it should be placed before.
4. Then go to **node_modules/foundation-sites/sass/settings/_settings.scss**, find there a default **util** import block at row number 63 and comment it. You do this because **util** imported before, so you aint need to duplicate that import.
5. Then go to **resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js** and change

`require('bootstrap-sass');`

**to**

`require('foundation-sites');

$(document).foundation();`

**You don't need to change anything in webpack.mix.js**